# Used "SimpleJdbcCall" to call stored procedure encountered Error java.lang.ClassCastException :weblogic .jdbc.wrapper.array_oracle_sql_Array

Tags: spring, plsql

**Oracle Types :** User Defined Datatypes

```
create or replace type id_array_input VARRAY(20) OF NUMBER

create or replace type output_data_array VARRAY(20) OF VARCHAR(25)
```

**Procedure**
Stored Procedure to be invoked

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TESTPROC(id_array in id_array_input,output_data out output_data_array)

as

declare 

doc_name varchar2(55);

begin

    output_data:=output_data_array();
    for i in 1..id_array.count loop
    select document_name into doc_name from document_details where doc_id =id_array(i);
    output_data.extend;
    output_data(i):=doc_name;

end loop;
end;
end TESTPROC;
```

**Spring Part:** Request Mapping containing call to procedure with In as an array of integers and out as an array of string

```
@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;  
private SimpleJdbcCall proceCall;

public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
}
@RequestMapping(value="/procedure",method=RequestMethod.GET,produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody Object getProcedure(){

        List<Integer> aa_array=new ArrayList<Integer>();
        aa_array.add(10);
        aa_array.add(20);
        aa_array.add(30);

        Integer[] int_array=new Integer[aa_array.size()];
        int_array=aa_array.toArray(int_array);

        proceCall=new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate).withProcedureName("TESTPROC")
                .declareParameters(new SqlParameter("id_array",OracleTypes.ARRAY,"id_array_input"),
                                   new SqlOutParameter("output_data",Types.ARRAY,"output_data_array" ,new SqlReturnArray()));
        Map in = Collections.singletonMap("id_array",new SqlArrayValue(int_array) );
        Map<String,Object> st_array=proceCall.execute(String[].class,in);
        return st_array;
    }
```

Comment: I don't know Java I'm afraid, but the procedure is invalid. Lose the `declare` and one of the two `end`s.

Comment: I have added semicolon in declare .it will compile now.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can also make it work by disabling the "Wrap Data Types" option in the WebLogic Administration Console under Services->Data Sources->Connection Pool->Advanced:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your example, exception is coming because of `new SqlReturnArray()`. Refer below code. This will work.

```
procedureCall=new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbctemplate.getDataSource()).withProcedureName("TESTPROC")                
                .declareParameters( new SqlParameter("id_array",OracleTypes.ARRAY, "COMPANY_COMMITTEE_ID_ARRAY")
                        ,new SqlOutParameter("output_data",Types.ARRAY, "STRING_ARRAY"));

        aa_array=alpha.toArray(aa_array);
        Map in =Collections.singletonMap("id_array",new SqlArrayValue(aa_array));       

        Array hi= procedureCall.executeFunction(Array.class,in); 
        String[] hh=(String[]) hi.getArray();
```